# StopAsync with ExecuteAsync on BackgroundService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

I am using hosted service to do some long running operation (checking open connection).

In sample on [Implement background tasks in microservices with IHostedService and the BackgroundService class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice) there there are two lines that log information when application is closing (double quoted in listed code)

But in my scenario I am never able to reach second log information?
I am wondering why Microsoft putted second line of logging if it is not reachable. Can any one explain to me?

```
public class GracePeriodManagerService : BackgroundService {        
    private readonly ILogger<GracePeriodManagerService> _logger;
    private readonly OrderingBackgroundSettings _settings;

    private readonly IEventBus _eventBus;

    public GracePeriodManagerService(IOptions<OrderingBackgroundSettings>> settings,
                                     IEventBus eventBus,
                                     ILogger<GracePeriodManagerService> logger)
    {
        //Constructor’s parameters validations...       
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug($"GracePeriodManagerService is starting.");

         stoppingToken.Register(() => 
                _logger.LogDebug($" GracePeriod background task is stopping."));

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug($"GracePeriod task doing background work.");

            // This eShopOnContainers method is querying a database table 
            // and publishing events into the Event Bus (RabbitMS / ServiceBus)
            CheckConfirmedGracePeriodOrders();

            await Task.Delay(_settings.CheckUpdateTime, stoppingToken);
        }

         _logger.LogDebug($"GracePeriod background task is stopping.");

    }

    protected override async Task StopAsync (CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
           // Run your graceful clean-up actions
    } 
}
```